# Does Twitter Bootstrap 3.0 offer a slide toggle select component?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a slide toggle select component for a mobile app. We are using twitter bootstrap 3.0 for the UI.

I don't see any documentation on bootstrap 3.0 that covers a slide toggle select component. Did they decide not to build that component for 3.0? If so, how can I create one?

I really want to keep using Bootstrap 3.0 for the responsive design elements. And I don't want to weigh my app down by adding jQuery mobile.

Comment: Please explain what a slide toggle select is?

Comment: We're looking for something a little more like the swipe toggle that is offered with jQuery Mobile. The swipe toggle they offer has a little more of an effect that is a swipe with the finger to activate instead of a touch with the finger. View the flip toggle switch at the bottom of this page: view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/sliders

Answer (score 6):

It does not come pre-made with Bootstrap, but here is one that I have used that was pretty good.

It's a switch toggle for Bootstrap.

http://bootstrapswitch.com/ (previously [http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/](https://web.archive.org/web/20161118212746/http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/))

Comment: Thank you for the reference! I'm will try this. I would like to still keep the question out there in case someone has a suggestion for a slide toggle. I would prefer to use a slide toggle instead of a switch toggle.

Comment: can you show me an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: We're looking for something a little more like the swipe toggle that is offered with jQuery Mobile. The swipe toggle they offer has a little more of an effect that is a swipe with the finger to activate instead of a touch with the finger. View the flip toggle switch at the bottom of this page: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/sliders/

Comment: That http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/ does not seems to be there anymore - it does not return any data. As alternatives, currently (mid 2017) http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/ and http://bootstrapswitch.com/ seem to be available.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a project that seems to do exactly what you want:

http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/

Answer (score 1):

Try this link: http://www.bootply.com/92189
It does not require additional css file. All it does is just only jQuery.

Comment: I am not looking for a boolean switch. I am looking for a slidable area, such as when you slide to unlock your iPhone. Thanks for the link though.